# Feed Array of Strings into Ruby Loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I'd like to write a quick method that can help me initialize a few fields in one of my ruby tables. This is what I have so far but it does not work. I would like to be able to feed an array of field names into this function so that I can get the whole initialization done in one loop.

```
fields =["field1","field2","field3","field4"]
tasks = Task.all

tasks.each do |task|
    fields.each do |field|
        if task.field.nil?
            task.update_attribute :field => true
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you mean:

```
fields = %w[field1 field2 field3 field4]
tasks = Task.all

tasks.each do |task|
  fields.each do |field|
    task.update_attribute :"#{field}" => true if task.send(field).nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is actually Rails, as it appears to be, you can use hash access:

```
task[field] = true if task[field].nil?
```

You would still need to `save` the modified record.

You may use `task.update_attribute(field, true)` instead: this will update the database immediately, but will do a transaction for each modified attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try to always use the least number of queries to the database

```
fields = ["field1","field2","field3","field4"]

fields.each do |field|
  Task.where({field => nil}).update_all({field => true})
end
```